# Edit reference shows empty in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, monodevelop

I'm newbie in Xamarin.  I'm using the latest stable version of Xamarin (6.1.4) on my MAC.

I created a Xamarin.Forms project (Forms App) PCL type of project, I checked the IPhone only (Portrait only). It created 3 projects....

ProjectX
ProjectX.iOS
ProjectX.Droid

Now I like to add some .NET assemblies in my ProjectX project to use the webservice or any other .NET assembly like **System.Data**, **system.web.webservice** but the strange thing is the list is EMPTY...

e.g. How to add System.Web.Webservices in this ProjectX project?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add reference into the PCL project or the iOS/Android projects?

Comment: Unfortunately, You cannot add a reference to any BCL such as `System.Web` to a PCL. You can although however add it to your platform specific projects.

Comment: I tried in the PCL project... I like to use a WEB Service... so the question is then how to use webservice and coding which is valid for Android and iOS? Where to add the code?  The whole idea is I like to consume a webservice.

Comment: There are plenty of samples on how to communicate with a web service in the [official documentation from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/).

Comment: I already looked at it... It's not clear... if you type webservice, it propose you RESTfull services info... I just like to know, if I have a WS how to consume that. I'm even happy with or without proxy class. The only solution I can think is double code in all platform projects, which  I don't like.